# I have the following problem when trying to merge two excel sheetsTypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed

Tags: python

```
    import pandas as pd

df_left = pd.read_excel('AAA.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

df_right = pd.read_excel('BBB.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1')
print(df_right)
df_right.rename(columns={'NO1': 'NUM'}, inplace=True)

df_result = pd.merge(left='df_left',
                     right='df_right',
                     how='left',
                     on='NUM')
df_result.to_excel('df_result.xlsx', index=None)
```

But I receive this error

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed
```

I do not understand what is causing this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try with `left=df_left` instead of `left='df_left',` ....

Answer (score 1):

change it to:

```
df_result = pd.merge(left=df_left,
                     right=df_right,
                     how='left',
                     on='NUM')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it must be because I didn't wake up.LOL